# Excel VBA Button Anchor

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have multiple buttons that are to the right of different tables, all stacked vertically. when I press the button it adds a new row to the top of the table and shifts the other rows down - exactly what i want. However it seems that the buttons are not moving with the first row of the tables so after a few clicks of each, everything is misaligned. how can i keep my buttons anchored to the first rows of their respective tables.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim mySheets
    Dim i As Long
    
    mySheets = Array("Highland")
    
    For i = LBound(mySheets) To UBound(mySheets)
        With Sheets(mySheets(i))
            .Range("OP_DATE").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Range("OP_DATE:lineOP").Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim mySheets
    Dim i As Long
    
    mySheets = Array("Highland")
    
    For i = LBound(mySheets) To UBound(mySheets)
        With Sheets(mySheets(i))
            .Range("P_DATE").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Range("P_DATE:lineP").Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim mySheets
    Dim i As Long
    
    mySheets = Array("Highland")
    
    For i = LBound(mySheets) To UBound(mySheets)
        With Sheets(mySheets(i))
            .Range("S_DATE").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Range("S_DATE:lineS").Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to play around with this but it should be pretty close. If you are adding multiple rows you will need to multiple the return of the function by that number.

This function gets the row height and column width in twips.

```
Public Function GetRowColumnTwips(r As Long, c As Long) As Variant
    Dim twips(1) As Long
    
    twips(0) = Rows(r).Height
    twips(1) = Columns(c).Width 'I put this in if you need it but I'm not actually using it here
    
    GetRowColumnTwips = twips
End Function
```

This sub uses the row height value to keep its place on the sheet.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim twips As Variant
    With Sheet1
        twips = GetRowColumnTwips(.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row, .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column)
        .Shapes(Application.Caller).Top = .Shapes(Application.Caller).Top - twips(0)
    End With
End Sub
```

You can drop the button event sub code into any of your button codes, the only thing that needs to change is the sheet in the `With` statement.

In your first button's code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim mySheets
    Dim i As Long
    Dim twips As Variant
    mySheets = Array("Highland")
    
    For i = LBound(mySheets) To UBound(mySheets)
        With Sheets(mySheets(i))
            .Range("OP_DATE").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Range("OP_DATE:lineOP").Borders.Weight = xlThin
            twips = Module1.GetRowColumnTwips(.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row, .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column)
            .Shapes(Application.Caller).Top = .Shapes(Application.Caller).Top - twips(0)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

For ActiveX Controls you'll need to refer to each button by name instead of relying upon the calling shape.

```
twips = Module1.GetRowColumnTwips(.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").TopLeftCell.Row, .OLEObjects("CommandButton1").TopLeftCell.Column)
.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Top = .OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Top - twips(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far - I'm brand new to this, where exactly should i drop the above function sub into?

Comment: The function you can place in a module or the sheet's codebehind doesn't really matter where that is, the sub you can place the code after you insert the row(s). Since you already have a `With` statement you really just need the `Dim` and the two lines within the `With`

Comment: Thank You! I put the function into a seperate module, but now I'm getting a Runtime error saying the item with the specified name wasnt found and when i debug it takes me to Twips = line of the button sub. any additional help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ohh you may need to do `Module1.GetRowColumnTwips` Or whatever the Module name is, and then put a `Public` in front of the Function definition.

Comment: I think Im getting closer! my function is in Module 2 so I made it a public function and modified the twips statement:   twips = Module2.GetRowColumnTwips(.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row, .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column) But im still getting the same error

Comment: Or when I use Module1 I get a different error for the first line Private Sub saying Compile error: method or data not found

Comment: I bet you have ActiveX controls instead of Form Controls, you'll have to change all the `Application.Caller` Lines to the name of the button, there isn't a way I know of to refer to the calling control (Without writing class modules to handle it).  Probably should have noticed that by the names of the subs, my bad. So any line with `Application.Caller` Will be `CommandButton1` in its place, and you'll need to update that for each button sadly.

Comment: Thats ok! NOW its saying index out of bounds

Comment: Lol, I don't use ActiveX often... They aren't shapes of course! `.OLEObjects("CommandButton1")` That replaces all instances of `.Shapes(Application.Caller)` And `.OLEObjects("CommandButton2")` etc for each button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237062/discussion-between-sserb1989-and-warcupine).